# Searching for messages by min and max date yields wrong results

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, java-time

I am using the `javax.mail` classes in order to connect to microsoft outlook and fetch mails.
What I would like to do is to find all of the messages that were sent between 2 dates.
I have the min and max dates as dates of type `ZonedDateTime`. For example:

```
ZonedDateTime minZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 6, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.systemDefault());

ZonedDateTime maxZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 6, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

My default time zone is `'Australia/Sydney'`. So in order to fetch all of the mails between those 2 dates I do the following:

```
 Date minDate = Date.from(minZonedDateTime.toInstant());
 Date maxDate = Date.from(maxZonedDateTime.toInstant());


 SentDateTerm minSentDateTerm = new SentDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.GE, minDate);
 SentDateTerm maxSentDateTerm = new SentDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.LE, maxDate);
 SearchTerm term = new AndTerm(maxSentDateTerm,minSentDateTerm);
 Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
 folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

 Message[] messages = folderInbox.search(term);
```

Now, when I print the sentDates of all of the recieved messages I have the following result:

```
 Tue Jun 20 19:01:57 AEST 2017
 Mon Jun 19 18:31:31 AEST 2017
 Sun Jun 18 18:54:26 AEST 2017
 Sun Jun 18 18:31:24 AEST 2017
 Sun Jun 18 01:08:46 AEST 2017
 Sat Jun 17 00:54:27 AEST 2017
 Fri Jun 16 00:27:56 AEST 2017
```

All of the messages are correctly fetched and belong to the interval except for the first message that has `sentDate` value of `(Tue Jun 20 19:01:57 AEST 2017)`
The sentDate of that message if bigger than the value of maxDate, which is proven by the result of `messages[0].getSentDate().compareTo(maxDate)` which is 1. How is this possible?

Comment: With no experience with `javax.mail` could it be that it compares only the date, not the time of day? I was speculating that in that case June 20 would be considered equal to June 20. And using `LT` instead of `LE` would fix. You can try…

Comment: That does not seem to be the case, because there is a mail with sent date `15/06/2017, 04:00` in my mailbox that is also not fetched (and it should be). If it only compared by date, then because of the GE it should have included that mail as well.

Comment: Sounds weird. If it were me, I’d start adjusting the hour-of-day value of your two `ZonedDateTime` objects to try to learn the limit for when those two email messages from 15th June and 20th June are included and when not.

Comment: I noticed you’re located in the Република Македонија (Republic of Macedonia) and got a thought: On 15/06/2017, 04:00 it was still 14/06 20:00 in Skopje, hence outside your interval. And on Tue Jun 20 19:01:57 AEST 2017 it was also Jun 20 (at 11:01) in Skopje. So if in spite of your timezone setting this time zone is interfering, and the dates (without times) are inclusive, it would explain. Are the time zones of your own computer and of the Outlook server both set to Australia/Sydney?

Comment: This code is part of a larger Spring application that sets the default TZ at startup. I also checked the generated `ZonedDateTime` objects and they were generated in `Australia/Sydney` TZ. The TZ on my own computer is `Europe/Skopje` , but I thought that the computer TZ does not matter as long as you have `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Sydney"))`. I will deffinitely try to change the time zone on my computer when I get on my pc tommorrow. The mail server shows me the mails sent date in `Australia/Sydney` time (even if I access it from Skopje TZ).

Comment: IMAP search definitely only compares dates, not times.  The [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) will show you exactly what the client is sending and what the server is returning.  (Also, there was a bug in searching that was fixed in JavaMail 1.5.3 so make sure you're using a version at least that new.)